# JasperReport - wrap text to show long text in textfield

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am using jasper report as reporting tool in my application. And I am wondering how can i wrap the long text by expanding the `reportElement` dynamically into vertical direction ( expanding the row size, not column width). Or Is there any way to achieve this? My approach below is truncating the long text "**Some very long name**". Can you please give me some suggestions?

**Output :**

[image]

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JasperDesign;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader;
import net.sf.jasperreports.view.JasperViewer;

public class JrUtils {
    public static void showJrReport(List objectList, String fileName, String title, Map parameters) {
        try {

            File f = new File(fileName);
            JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(f.getAbsolutePath());
            JRBeanCollectionDataSource ds = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(objectList);
            JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, ds);
            JasperViewer jv = new JasperViewer(jasperPrint, false);
            jv.setTitle(title);
            jv.setVisible(true);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Person> pList = new ArrayList<Person>();

        Person p1 = new Person();
        p1.setPersonName("Some Name ");
        p1.setAddress("Nepal - Address Fits Here");

        Person p2 = new Person();
        p2.setPersonName("Some very long name");
        p2.setAddress("Nepal - Address Fits Here");

        pList.add(p1);
        pList.add(p2);

        showJrReport(pList, "testReport.jrxml", "Test Report", new HashMap<Object, Object>());
    }

}
```

Jasper Report JrXML file - testReport.jrxml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report name" pageWidth="250" pageHeight="400" columnWidth="210" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="2.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <field name="personName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="address" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="23" splitType="Stretch">
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="88" height="23"/>
            </rectangle>
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement x="88" y="0" width="122" height="23"/>
            </rectangle>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="88" height="23"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Name]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="88" y="0" width="122" height="23"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Address]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="21" splitType="Stretch">
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="88" height="21"/>
            </rectangle>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="88" height="21"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{personName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement x="88" y="0" width="122" height="21"/>
            </rectangle>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="88" y="0" width="122" height="21"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{address}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

**I found the answer myself :**

I did some extra research about the properties of  `textField` and `rectangle` components. And found that I need to set the following properties.

**For rectangle :**

```
        <rectangle>
            <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" ... />
        </rectangle>
```

**For textField :**

```
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            ...
        </textField>
```

Output as expected :

[image]

The `<detail> ...</detail>` section after correction :

```
<detail>
        <band height="21" splitType="Stretch">
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="0" y="0" width="88" height="21"/>
            </rectangle>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement x="2" y="0" width="84" height="21"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{personName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="88" y="0" width="122" height="21"/>
            </rectangle>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement x="90" y="0" width="118" height="21"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{address}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
```

**UPDATE**

You can also set property `net.sf.jasperreports.print.keep.full.text` to `true` to achieve that across your all reports.

Comment: but what if we want to push down other elements down because of this. It doesn't seem to work in this case

Comment: Can this be used for static text?

Comment: I'm not sure. Could you try?

Answer (score 10):

Also you can make the truncation elegant by using the following properties set to the textfield. Check this [sample](https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/need-way-text-field-show-much-content-possible-without-word-break-based-truncation)

```
net.sf.jasperreports.text.truncate.at.char 
net.sf.jasperreports.text.truncate.suffix 
net.sf.jasperreports.print.keep.full.text
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Text Field Properties then set `Text Adjust` to `StretchHeight`.

Answer (score 0):

StretchHeight is truncating my data in the subreport when it falls on the page break