# Report with Horizontal print order: Issue with truncating long text in textField

Tags: jasper-reports, report, export-to-pdf

I am using *JasperReports 4.0.2* (not tied to it in the long run, but for now we are).

I am having a problem with a sub-report which is set up to support 3 columns of data. I have 2 text fields which are being printed, and when the data is too long for the text field it is being truncated. After following advice in [JasperReport - wrap text to show long text in textfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10631806/jasperreport-wrap-text-to-show-long-text-in-textfield) post I am still struggling to get the text field to overflow properly to display the data.

Here is my report file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="record" language="groovy" columnCount="3" printOrder="Horizontal" pageWidth="572" pageHeight="752" columnWidth="157" columnSpacing="50" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0">
    <field name="geoName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="count" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <variable name="count" class="java.lang.String">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[new java.text.DecimalFormat("###,###,###,###").format($F{count})]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <detail>
        <band height="15" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="15" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" positionType="Float"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{geoName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement x="90" y="0" width="67" height="15" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" positionType="Float"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{count}]]></textFieldExpression>
             </textField>
             <line>
                <reportElement x="182" y="0" width="1" height="15" forecolor="#CCCCCC" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" positionType="Float"/>
            </line>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

The report generally works properly and expands horizontally as it should, but if the data in either of the text fields is too long, it simply truncates it. The only workaround I have is to increase the band size, but that doesn't look good. I have also tried the ***`isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"`*** flag as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stretch a row if data overflows in jasper reports](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1205410) post. You should read carefully the [answer by @mike](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2806486/876298), especially the quote from *JasperReports Ultimate Guide*

Comment: It isn't a duplicate, because that user isn't using multiple columns, nor are they using a horizontal fill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found my answer, and it is just a limitation of jasper.

http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/horizontal/index.html

> When filling report templates horizontally, dynamic text fields inside
>   the detail section do not stretch to their entire text content,
>   because this might cause misalignment on the horizontal axis of
>   subsequent detail sections. The detail band actually behaves the same
>   as the page and column footers, preserving its declared height when
>   horizontal filling is used.

So long story short, when filling horizontally you can't expect a vertical expansion as well, bummer!